# How to get page's ID if I know the title only?

Tags: title, id, get-the-title, get-the-id

Is there an exact opposite funciton to this one:

```
get_the_title(ID)
```

I know there's:

```
get_the_id()
```

But it doesn't seem to accept any arguments.

So, basically, I'm looking for something like:

```
$title = 'Something';
get_the_id($title);
```

I already know this solution:

```
 global $wpdb;
 $post_name = get_query_var('name');
 $post_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = $post_name");
```

But maybe there's something bulit-in that I'm missing?

Comment: How are you getting the title?

Comment: [shortcode title="User inserts title here"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how to get it via the title, but you can get it via the slug (which is often more useful in my experience) using this:

http://erikt.tumblr.com/post/278953342/get-a-wordpress-page-id-with-the-slug

Just change "$page" to "$post" if you want to return slugs for posts instead of pages.

G'luck!

Comment: **Note:** this will not work for sub-pages (pages that are children of other pages).

Answer (score 1):

[`get_page_by_title( $title, [$output = 'object'], [$post_type = 'page'] )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) exists for this very purpose. I'm using it in one of my projects now to display all attachments for a particular page in my sidebar:

```
if ( $oPage = get_page_by_title('Proudly Supporting...') ) {

  $children = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'numberposts'    => 3,
    'post_status'    => null,
    'post_parent'    => $oPage->ID, /* Using the Page ID */
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
  ));

  if ( $children ) {
    /* Do something with the children */
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used the next code:

```
$my_title = 'My title';
global $wpdb;
$mypost = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = '" . $my_title . "' " );
echo $mypost->ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a built in function to do it. 
Use:
    get_page_by_title();

See the referrence here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title